# Heine-Borel property on metric spaces.

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose a metric space has a bounded metric and it has a Heine-Borel property. So each set is bounded, is any closed set then is compact?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. That is what Heine-Borel property says.

Note that in this case the whole space $X$ itself if compact.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the case when the whole space itself is not compact.

Comment: @RichardKim You are putting conditions that make $X$ compact. You are assuming that $X$ is bounded and it is always closed so H-B  property implies that $X$ is compact. If a metric space is not compact the either it does not have H -B property or the metric is not bounded.

Comment: There are infinite-dimensional spaces that have H -B property and they are metrizable, eg. nuclear Frechet mnaifolds

Comment: Yes, but the metrics on them are not bounded. @RichardKim

Comment: Metrics are bounded, indeed.  Furthermore, each metric space has an equivalent bounded metric

Comment: @RichardKim Heine Borel peoperty refers to a particular metric. You cannot. change the metric to an equivalent metric and use H-B property.